# Python: compare values in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I would need to merge using pandas two dataframes with two columns: locid and locname; then, I would need to find the rows that having same locid, they have different value for locname

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input (text), images are not acceptable, also provide iniput for your **two** inputs, and the matching expected output.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering, You have 2 Pandas dataframe and each were having `locid` and `locname`. You want to get the resultant dataframe with column `locid`, `locname_table1`, `locname_table2`.

Then you can try below code -

```
resultant_df = pd.merge(df_table1, df_table2, on='locid', suffixes=['_table1', '_table2'])
```